# Strange compile-time representation of cyrillic string in Websharper

Tags: websharper

I crete new Websharper Sitlet project and declare string within main module like this

[image]

Next, I set a breakpoint, start debugging and found that the string does not contain what I wrote in it.
But how could it be?

And all cyrilic outup, which was created by the project by default, looks like this

[image]

Upd

Here is full solution with correct strings: https://yadi.sk/d/z-wOkQGQf7QTS
And here is the same with bad output: https://yadi.sk/d/Vy2hmOudf7QaT

I can not realise what is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just open and save your files, containing Cyrillic characters: Client.fs, Main.fs ... to Unicode, rebuild the solution and it will show Cyrillic on the application web page.